# Webex AttachementActionData usage

Tags: botframework

How is this class used? If there is a submit button using Action.Submit on an adaptive card, how does the Microsoft Bot get this message?

So this question doesn't get flagged as too generic, there is a Webex adapter connected to a Microsoft bot using this exact demo.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-adapter-connect-webex?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

The OnMessageActivityAsync message gets the message from the bot, for example, if the user types "Hello", and the bot responds back with an adaptive card that has the action "Action.Submit" that will give the user a card with a submit button. Now, if the user clicks "submit", Webex should send something back to the bot. I don't think it's a message, because I never receive a message. Webex has, on it's side of documentation, a webhook with ActionAttachments. But after creating this webhook and clicking submit, what is the bot supposed to receive?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was to change the Webex access token from the auto-generated token to the bot's access token. After doing this, the Action Attachment was working and the bot received the Event Activity.